# What is the most common or average aspect ratio for mobile devices?

Tags: android, ios, mobile

I know aspect ratio's can be defined by the market in question eg. the average aspect ration in India may differ from that of America. But what would you think would be the most common and or average aspect ratio of mobile devices universally speaking?

Does anyone have any stats on mobile devices in different continents?

I'm currently attempting to create the most dynamic media that will present perfectly on the most devices as possible.

EDIT: Media format must be in .jpeg

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Just use "aspect fill" for the media file and provide it in suitable resolution.

Comment: Please see what Questions [**Are On-Topic**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and which ones [**Are not On-Topic**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [**How do I ask a good question**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I found that every Android device had one of the following aspect ratios (from most square to most rectangular):

- 4:3
- 3:2
- 8:5
- 5:3
- 16:9

And if you consider portrait devices separate from landscape devices you'll also find the inverse of those ratios (3:4, 2:3, 5:8, 3:5, and 9:16)

Answer (score -2):

According to [appbrain](https://www.appbrain.com/stats/top-devices-by-country), the samsung galaxy s7 is the most popular device in the united states. Afterwards is the s5, then the s6.

Comment: The question was about popular screen resolution, not popular device.